# Create additional column for totals and include in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have written the query:

```
SELECT        
RTRIM(BLDGCODE) AS BLDGCODE, 
RTRIM(FLOORCODE) AS FLOORCODE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) LIKE '%fs' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLR_SHARED,          
SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) LIKE '%bs' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BLDG_SHARED, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) LIKE '%as' AND rtrim(spacetype) NOT IN ('U-TLS-AS', 'U-PARK-AS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLR_ASSIGNABLE,
SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) = 'U-TLS-AS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TENANT
FROM FMA0
WHERE
bldgcode in ('us0385', 'us0566')
GROUP BY BLDGCODE, FLOORCODE
ORDER BY BLDGCODE, FLOORCODE
```

Which returns the result:

```
BLDGCODE FLOORCODE  FLR_SHARED  BLDG_SHARED FLR_ASSIGNABLE  TENANT
US0385     01-T        0            0           3              1
US0385     02-T       10            0          28              0
US0385     03-T       27            0         404              0
US0385     04-T       83            0         251              0
US0385     05-T       75            0         132              0
US0385     06-T       85            0         191              0
US0385     07-T       73            0         210              0
US0385     08-T       60            1         250              0
US0385     09-T       29            0         270              0
US0385     10-T       22            0         385              0
US0385     11-T        8           23           0              0
US0385   CELL-01      11            5          59              0
US0385   CELL-02       8            3          49              0
US0385   CELL-03       0            3           0              0
US0385   CELL-T       32            0         114              0
US0566      1          0            7           0              3
US0566      2          0            0           0              2
US0566      3          0            0           0              2
US0566      4          0            0           0              2
US0566      LG         4            3           0              4
```

This is fine but I need an additional column that includes the sum of **FLR_ASSIGNABLE** for each **BLDGCODE**, so from the example data above I should see:

```
BLDGCODE FLOORCODE  FLR_SHARED  BLDG_SHARED FLR_ASSIGNABLE  BLDG_ASSIGNABLE   TENANT
US0385     01-T        0            0           3             2346               1
US0385     02-T       10            0          28             2346               0
US0385     03-T       27            0         404             2346               0
US0385     04-T       83            0         251             2346               0
US0385     05-T       75            0         132             2346               0
US0385     06-T       85            0         191             2346               0
US0385     07-T       73            0         210             2346               0
US0385     08-T       60            1         250             2346               0
US0385     09-T       29            0         270             2346               0
US0385     10-T       22            0         385             2346               0
US0385     11-T        8           23           0             2346               0
US0385   CELL-01      11            5          59             2346               0
US0385   CELL-02       8            3          49             2346               0
US0385   CELL-03       0            3           0             2346               0
US0385   CELL-T       32            0         114             2346               0
US0566      1          0            7           0                0               3
US0566      2          0            0           0                0               2
US0566      3          0            0           0                0               2
US0566      4          0            0           0                0               2 
US0566      LG         4            3           0                0               4
```

Also, is it then possible to then filter out the results

```
  Where FLR_SHARED > 0 AND FLR_ASSIGNABLE = 0
```

OR

```
  Where BLDG_SHARED > 0 AND BLDG_ASSIGNABLE = 0
```

so I only get

```
BLDGCODE FLOORCODE  FLR_SHARED  BLDG_SHARED FLR_ASSIGNABLE  BLDG_ASSIGNABLE   TENANT
US0385     11-T        8           23           0             2346               0
US0566      1          0            7           0                0               3
US0566      LG         4            3           0                0               4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you can do what you want as using a structure like this:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             sum(bldg_assignable) over (partition by BLDGCODE) as bldg_sum
      from cte
     ) cte
where FLR_SHARED > 0 AND FLR_ASSIGNABLE = 0 and
      BLDG_SHARED > 0 AND bldg_sum = 0;
```

The key idea is to use window functions at one level (in a subquery or CTE).  And then filter in an outer query.

Comment: Thanks, I need to do this over several buildings at once so how does the "partition by" work for multiple bldg codes

Comment: @FredTheDog . . . That should be `BLDGCODE`.  Apparently, I confused a value with the column header.  To answer your question, it should work with the `partition by`.

Comment: @Gorgon....thanks, your code needed a little tweaking along with my original but I have it working. Needed to remove my `ORDER BY` statement, change your `SUM(BLDG_ASSIGNABLE)` to `SUM(FLR_ASSIGNABLE)` and change the `AND` statement in the `WHERE` clause to an `OR`...now gets me exactly what I need....really appreciate your help as I would never have got the on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you are looking for:

```
    WITH CTE
AS
(SELECT        
    RTRIM(BLDGCODE) AS BLDGCODE, 
    RTRIM(FLOORCODE) AS FLOORCODE, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) LIKE '%fs' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLR_SHARED,          
    SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) LIKE '%bs' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BLDG_SHARED, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) LIKE '%as' AND rtrim(spacetype) NOT IN ('U-TLS-AS', 'U-PARK-AS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLR_ASSIGNABLE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rtrim(spacetype) = 'U-TLS-AS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TENANT
    FROM FMA0
    WHERE
    bldgcode in ('us0385', 'us0566')
    GROUP BY BLDGCODE, FLOORCODE
)
SELECT CTE.*, SUM(FLR_ASSIGNABLE) AS BLDG_ASSIGNABLE FROM CTE
where (FLR_SHARED > 0 AND FLR_ASSIGNABLE = 0) or
      (BLDG_SHARED > 0 AND SUM(FLR_ASSIGNABLE) = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks...though when I run this I get an error
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'CTE.BLDGCODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If I add a GROUP BY clause to the end of your code that includes all the flieds in the first SELECT statement the BLDG_ASSIGNABLE column is not the total for the bldg but is the same as the numbers provided in the FLR_ASSIGNABLE column